# scheduled tasks during sysprep from MSI

Tags: windows, wix, windows-installer, scheduled-tasks

I want to be able to run an application X hours after a new user creates an account. I'm in Windows sysprep and installing an MSI, and the MSI needs to schedule a task to run 48 hours after a user creates an account. I looked at the `schtasks.exe` but I can't figure out:

1. How to invoke it from the MSI during sysprep
2. How to schedule it for 48 hours after a user logs on, although there is no user at this time.
3. What happens if a user isn't logged in when the 48 hour windows elapses.

Help?

Comment: I work in an Enterprise IT environment with technologies such as Sysprep / MDT / SCCM and I don't really understand what you are trying to do. Are these domain joined machines?  Please explain in more detail. What other infrastructure do you have available to you?  (GPO, Software Distribution )

Comment: Nothing to do with domain. I need to install an app which auto-runs in 48 hours after a user creates a new account on the machine.

Comment: It's still not clear.  48 hours after the account is created or 48 hours after the account first logs in?   What context does the program run in?  System, the user who created the account or the newly created account?   Does it have to be exactly 48 hours or atleast 48 hours?   Could it run multiple times until it succeeds in case 48 hours is an estimate?

Comment: It'll also depend on what the task is. If it needs to run with user's credentials then it can't run at all unless you know the account credentials/password. And a user can create multiple accounts, so is it for every created account or just the first one?

Comment: Thanks for helping guys - sorry I wasn't clear enough. It needs to run 48 hours after the first user logs in, and can run as system or the user. It needs to be trigger roughly 48 hours after the user account is created, but not exactly. I guess it can run multiple times. This also needs to run for each account created.